# Getting error for Dynamodb VPC endpoint on Cloudformation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am new to cft ,I am !ref to VpcID function and there I am parameterize to vpcIds,I need to get vpcid as its mandatory field for dynamodb endpont.Could someone please suggest me how can I pass this vpcId .

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          const AWS = require('aws-sdk');//code goes here 
      FunctionName:
        Ref: LambdaFuncName
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Role: !GetAtt IAMRole.Arn
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          Ref: SecurityGroups
        SubnetIds:
          Ref: Subnets
    DependsOn:
      - DynamoDBTable
  DynamoDBTable:
    Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
    Properties:
      TableName:
        Ref: DynamoDBTableName
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: '5'
        WriteCapacityUnits: '5'
    DependsOn:
      - IAMRole
  APIGatewayRestAPI:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      Name:
        Ref: APIName
    DependsOn:
      - LambdaFunction
  APIGatewayResource:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref APIGatewayRestAPI
      ParentId: !GetAtt
        - APIGatewayRestAPI
        - RootResourceId
      PathPart:
        Ref: LambdaFuncName
    DependsOn:
      - APIGatewayRestAPI
  APIGatewayMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref APIGatewayRestAPI
      ResourceId: !Ref APIGatewayResource
      HttpMethod: POST
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
      Integration:
        Type: AWS
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub
          - >-
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaFuncNameArn}/invocations
          - LambdaFuncNameArn: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
    DependsOn:
      - APIGatewayResource
  APIGatewayDeployment:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref APIGatewayRestAPI
      StageName:
        Ref: EnvironmentName
    DependsOn:
      - APIGatewayMethod
  APIGatewayPermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
    DependsOn:
      - APIGatewayDeployment
  IAMRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: Policy_api-lambda-db
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'dynamodb:BatchGetItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:BatchWriteItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:TagResource'
                  - 'dynamodb:UntagResource'
                  - 'dynamodb:PutItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:DeleteItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:GetItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:Scan'
                  - 'dynamodb:Query'
                  - 'dynamodb:UpdateItem'
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces'
                  - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterface'
                  - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface'
                  - 'ec2:DescribeInstances'
                  - 'ec2:AttachNetworkInterface'
                Resource: '*'
  DynamoDBEndpoint:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint"
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Sub "com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.dynamodb"
      VpcId: !Ref VpcID
      PolicyDocument: {
        "Id": "Policy",
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "Statement",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123412341234:table/test",
            "Principal": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
  VpcID:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      Name:
        Ref: vpcId
Parameters:
  LambdaFuncName:
    Type: String
    Default: Lambda_api-lambda-db
  DynamoDBTableName:
    Type: String
    Default: Dynamo_api-lambda-db
  APIName:
    Type: String
    Default: API_api-lambda-db
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Default: Prod
  SecurityGroups:
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>'
  Subnets:
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>'
  vpcId:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id'
```

Here I am getting error **Encounter unsupported property name while creating VpcID** ,my main focus is to create lambda within the vpc and create ane dynamodb endpoint to access dynamodb privately .Please suggest me on this .

Comment: What is the exact error? And do you have your resources in a Resource: section?

Comment: yes ,have posted in full ,could you please check now

Comment: And what is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: 1 validation error detected: Value '[AWS::ApiGateway::Resource, AWS::DynamoDB::Table, AWS::ApiGateway::Method, AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint, AWS::EC2::VPC::Id, AWS::IAM::Role, AWS::Lambda::Function, AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment, AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi, AWS::Lambda::Permission]' at 'typeNameList' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 204, Member must have length greater than or equal to 10, Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}::[A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}::[A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}(::MODULE){0,1}]

Comment: this error is coming while I am adding VpcID:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id'

Comment: There is no type 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id' What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi ,I need to get vpcId in VPCEndpoint section .Could you pls suggest how to get vpcId as this is mandatory field .

Comment: You need to have a VPC for that. You are creating a DynamoDB endpoint with no VPC. Why?

Comment: I want to create DynamodbEndpoint with vpc only  ,how to get that vpc ,that was my doubt .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233236/discussion-between-chintamani-and-robert-kossendey).